# How to save solr queries in a log file

Tags: apache, logging, solr

I am using apache solr 4.10. I know that there is a log file that contains informations about the solr queries. But other than query information, it also gives many other information. I have to log only queries run by users so that I can process on then to know what users is searching. How I will do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose what you want to log using `logParamsList` parameter in your query as it is described in [solr documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+Logging).

```
http://youwebsite.com/request?q=XXX&logParamsList=q
```